# What is the error in my code?

Tags: c++

I am solving [Project Euler problem 29](http://projecteuler.net/problem=29). I have a brute force approach just mapping all the numbers found as true if they don't exist in the map. The answer i'm getting is 9216 which is incorrect. Where is this going wrong?
I've tried using a set as well but it's all the same.

```
int main()
{
map <long double,bool> m;
long double x;

int c=0;
for(int i=2;i<=100;i++)
{
    for(int j=2;j<=100;j++)
    {
        x=pow((long double)i,(long double)j);
        if(m.find(x) == m.end())
        {
            m.insert ( pair<long double,bool>(x,true) );
            c++;
            cout<<x<<endl;
        }
    }
}
cout<<c<<endl;
```

}

EDIT:
I've changed this line

```
m[x]=true;
```

to

```
m.insert ( pair<long double,bool>(x,true) );
```

The answer still the same.

Comment: You are not inserting anything to the map. Are you?

Comment: isn't m[x]=true an unsafe shortcut to insert something to the map?

Comment: `m[x] = true` will insert the key `x` if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Did you try printing out the values you store? May be you can try with a smaller number and see if the precision is correct. Because,  when you try to store large values, precision will be lost.

Comment: Your code gives the correct answer when I [run it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y0jKJi). The only thing I changed was commenting out the display of `x` in the loop.

Comment: Yes that's what I think is where the error might be but i'm not sure.
I did try printing the values and i'm getting the large values in the form of 1e+200. Is that the error?

Comment: @Blastfurnace: You also changed the map to use `double` keys instead of `long double`.

Comment: @user2357112: I changed it back and got the same correct answer, ideone link updated. (The change was from my testing, sorry).

Comment: @Blastfurnace : I don't understand. Then where was the error? I'm using codeblocks. Is it something to do with the compiler or IDE?

Comment: Note that `long double` means different things to different compilers.

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet: Sorry, but I don't have a good answer. Possibly compiler options. What compiler settings are you using?

Comment: `pow` isn't guaranteed to give the same result on different systems, and it's only ever accurate to within 1 ulp, not 0.5.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: I see.. Thanks though, at least i know my code wasn't wrong.

Comment: I just went through the forums and saw that this
    m.insert(pow((double)i,(double)j));
    cout<<m.size()<<endl;
was all i had to do with a set <double>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using doubles, my guess is that you obtain repeated numbers that are not exactly the same in the double representation (so they occupy different entries in the map). Try creating a map that indexes integers.

Comment: Integers won't help; no C++ integer type is big enough. (These problems are a lot easier in languages like Python that have built-in bignums.)

Comment: This is my guess. Tried the exact some approach in a quick Python script and got the correct answer. However, some of the results (like `pow (100, 100)` are too big to fit into a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Although they can't solve the Euler problem, I think they solve the programming error (you can try with smaller limits to make sure).

Comment: So you mean to convert the a^b into an integer type and then map it?
I tried this but the long long int appears to be too small i guess since i got the answer as 997.

Comment: You can also create a map of doubles with your own comparison function, where you can take small differences between doubles into account.

Comment: Yeap C++ integers were too small.

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet: Floating point is no better, as the precision is still very limited. If you get the right answer with floating point (and without extensive numerical analysis), it's pure luck. To do this right, you'll need bignum support, or you'll need to use more number-theoretical methods to compute the answer without hundred-digit computations.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure. but looks like you have not added entries in map "m".
So, it is considering garbage values while finding.

Comment: I changed it to insert but it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

`exp` will produce a result in a `double` not `long double` as those are not used anymore. The compiler will convert any long double to double for you.
Doubles have a limited precision and `exp` will return slightly different results for two operations causing the map to hold extra values.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
#include <set>

int main()
{
    set <double> m;

    for (int i = 2; i <= 100; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 100; ++j)
        {
            m.insert(pow((double)i, (double)j));
        }
    }

    cout << m.size() << endl;
}
```